# Custom post type within a subdirectory

Tags: custom-post-types

I've searched around but have not been able to find an answer to my question.

What I'm trying to do is create a custom post type that exists within a sub-directory, not just after the root as is default.

For example right now I have:

http://www.mysite.com/custom-post-type

I would like to have:

http://www.mysite.com/subdirectory/custom-post-type

The reason I'm trying to do this is that I have a client that now has additional clients that I would like to have named as a sub-directory, and not an entirely new sub domain.

I was planning on creating custom post types to create the additional blogs or the two other clients, but I can't find a way of having a sub-directory first.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm decently versed in WP but not an expert, so I'm hoping there is an easy-ish method.

Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), add the subdirectory to the `has_archive` argument, and as the `slug` argument of the `rewrite` argument:

```
$args = array(
    // ... other args removed for clarity
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'subdirectory/custom-post-type' ),
    'has_archive' => 'subdirectory/custom-post-type',
    // ...
);
register_post_type( 'your_cpt', $args );
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do the same thing with taxonomies? I tried putting the same path into the rewrite slug but I'm having trouble with it picking up my taxonomy-taxonomyname.php file. Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: It should work for taxonomies as well. add the code you are using to the question, or perhaps it's best to ask a new question and provide the details there.